# measure of limsup positive for infinitely many terms

Tags: measure-theory

let $(X, M, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let ${E_k}$ be in $M$.  if $\mu(\cup E_k) < \infty$, and $\mu(E_k) \ge c > 0$ for infinitely many $k$'s for some $c$, then $\mu(\limsup E_k) > 0$.  Can someone explain why, I don't see where the condition  $\mu(\cup E_k) <\infty$ is used, why can this not be removed? an example might help.

Comment: You should write your math symbols in latex. Also, what is $\limsup E_k$? I am not familiar with taking the limsup of a sequence of sets

Answer (score 0):

Recall that by definition, $\limsup_k E_k=\bigcap_{l\geqslant 1}\bigcup_{j\geqslant l}A_j$. By the assumption, we have $\mu\left(\bigcup_{j\geqslant l}A_j\right)\geqslant c$ for any $l$.

Now use the following:

> If $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a measure space, $(A_n,n\geqslant 1)$ is an non-increasing sequence and $\mu(A_1)$ is finite, then $\mu\left(\bigcap_nA_n\right)=\lim_n\mu(A_n)$.

The condition about finiteness of the measure of the union cannot be removed, for example when $X$ is the real line with Lebesgue measure and $A_n:=(n,+\infty)$.